# class-validator: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I am getting the following error when trying a minimal example with `class-validator`:

> Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
> Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Object'

Code:

```js
import { IsEmail } from 'class-validator'

class Example {
    @IsEmail()
    email: string
}
```

I have installed `class-validator` using `npm i class-validator` at version `0.14.0`. The only thing I have changed in my `tsconfig.json` is setting `"strictPropertyInitialization": false`.